# How frequent does Lifelog uploads the data to its platform data store

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

I want to know how frequent does Lifelog uploads the data it collected to the Lifelog Platform Data store. Cause I want to be able to check in real time what activity the user is doing etc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is going to be difficult for you to consistently pull data in real time. Here is the timing for the updates though.

- The logger normally uploads data once every hour.
- Once every 15 minutes if the user has a connected smart band.​
- Once every 15 minutes if the user has added the Lifelog widget.
- Once every 3 minutes when the application is open.